# Starting several `ssh` sessions, each with forwarding to a different port

Tags: ssh

I have an alias that launches a custom `ssh` command with port forwarding that looks like this:

```
ssh -Y -L 8888:localhost:8888 hostname
```

This of course works fine for the first session I launch for the same host, but for subsequent times the forwarding will fail since port 8888 will already be in use.

What I want to do is come up with a way that each time I started an `ssh` connection to the same server the port will automatically adjust so that each different `ssh` connection will have its own separate port to forward to.

So, for example, the first time I issue the command, it'll be equivalent to

```
ssh -Y -L 8888:localhost:8888 hostname
```

the second time it'll be equivalent to

```
ssh -Y -L 8889:localhost:8889 hostname
```

and so on.

I know I can do that using Python or whatever, but I was wondering if there's an easier solution than writing my own (possibly kinda complicated) script to do it. Is that possible?

PS.: I know I can do this manually somewhat easily, but I launch several of these a day, and it would require me to not only type a lot more things, but also to keep track of which ports are already in use and which aren't.

Comment: You're going to have to write *some* sort of script, but it can be a shell script and probably doesn't need to be terribly complicated.

Comment: Your title references X11 forwarding to different ports, but your question seems to be about a simple (non-X11) port forward. Are you aware that the -Y and -L options work independently of each other, and the -L option isn't going to affect the X11 forwarding?

Comment: @Kenster Yes! Sorry, I changed my question midway and now it's confusing. I'll edit. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a short script that does the thing you've described. It works by attempting to lock a file named after the port number, and if that fails, incrementing the port number and trying again.

The port lock files are created in `$HOME/.ssh/ports`. They aren't cleaned up after they've been created, but that's okay; we're not checking for presence; we're acquiring a file lock.

This scripts doesn't care if you're connecting to the same server each time or to a different server; each connection will get a unique port.

```
#!/bin/bash

PORTPATH="$HOME/.ssh/ports"

port=8888
while :; do

  # We use the -E option to specify a custom exit code so that we can
  # differentiate between "failed to lock file" and "ssh failed for some
  # reason".
  flock -n -E 121 "$PORTPATH/$port" \
    ssh -Y -L "${port}:localhost:${port}" "$@" && break
  exitcode=$?

  if (( exitcode == 121 )); then
    (( port++ ))
    continue
  fi

  exit $exitcode
done
```

If I save this script in a file named `portfw.sh` and run it three times, like this:

```
sh portfw.sh remote.example.com
```

I'll see the following processes in the output of `ps`:

```
flock -n -E 121 /home/lars/.ssh/ports/8888 ssh -Y -L 8888:localhost:8888 remote.example.com
flock -n -E 121 /home/lars/.ssh/ports/8889 ssh -Y -L 8889:localhost:8889 remote.example.com
flock -n -E 121 /home/lars/.ssh/ports/8890 ssh -Y -L 8890:localhost:8890 remote.example.com
```